# How do I use beautify in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I've found the beautify extension in Ace editor but I don't see any examples of how to use it. Here's what I have so far:

```js
var beautiful = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify");
beautiful.beautify();
```

but I get the error:

```
Result of expression 'e' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like this works:

```js
var beautify = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify"); // get reference to extension
var editor = ace.edit("editor"); // get reference to editor
    beautify.beautify(editor.session);
```

It requires that you pass in the Ace Editor session as the first parameter. In my original question, I did not pass in any variables and that was throwing an error.

Note: It did not work well which was mentioned on the extensions release notes. It was not working well enough to use.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: don't forget to include ext-beautify.js

Comment: Add this line into your html:
```<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/ext-beautify.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>```

Comment: Is this an different version than the one that comes with ace?

Comment: Not sure. This is the version I am using, which is the same version as the main Ace.jd `1.2.6`. The result is ugly though (not fully beautified).

Comment: @ErazerBrecht 's solution is much better (more beautified).

Comment: I'm the author of this extension. I recently submitted a major rewrite which works a lot better especially with mixed mode documents which js beautify isn't so good at.

Comment: Any idea on how to customize beautify options? Eg: auto-indents

Answer (score 9):

I didn't get it working

```js
var beautify = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify"); // get reference to extension
```

**Beautify** was always `undefined`.

After a while I gave up.

And used the external Beautify library ([Link](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/blob/master/js/lib/beautify.js))

```js
function beatify() {
  var val = editor.session.getValue();
  //Remove leading spaces
  var array = val.split(/\n/);
  array[0] = array[0].trim();
  val = array.join("\n");
  //Actual beautify (prettify)
  val = js_beautify(val);
  //Change current text to formatted text
  editor.session.setValue(val);
}
```

Comment: above link has been moved to - https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify or https://beautifier.io/

Comment: Probably you are getting `undefined` because you haven't imported `ext-beautify.js` file

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Ended up **building a simplified prettify method** that fit my needs (which are not to have everything on the same line).

note I was using the [react version](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) of Ace Editor but same applies to JS. It does not support comments as my generated code does not contain them and you may need to expand the method if you wish to support them.

```
const html = prettifyHtml('<div id="root"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><a href="#">hello there</a><p>What <strong>is</strong> this? <br /> yes</p></div><div class="col-lg-6"></div></div></div></div>');
const scss = prettifyScss('.container { strong {color:green; background-color:white; border:1px solid green; &:hover {cursor:pointer} }  }');

<AceEditor
     mode="html" // or "scss"
     theme="github"
     defaultValue={html} // or scss
     onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
 />
```

**html:**

```
export const prettifyHtml = (html) => {
    let indent = 0,
        mode = 'IDLE',
        inTag = false,
        tag = '',
        tagToCome = '',
        shouldBreakBefore = false,
        shouldBreakAfter = false,
        breakBefore = ['p', 'ul', 'li'],
        breakAfter = ['div', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'p', 'ul', 'li'];

    return html
        .split('')
        .reduce((output, char, index) => {

            if (char === '<') {
                tagToCome = whichTag(html, index);
                shouldBreakBefore = tagToCome && breakBefore.indexOf(tagToCome) >= 0;
                mode = 'TAG';
                inTag = true;
                output += (shouldBreakBefore ? br(indent) : '') + '<';
            } else if (char === '/' && mode == 'TAG') {
                mode = 'CLOSING_TAG'
                inTag = true;
                output += '/';
            } else if (char === ' ') {
                inTag = false;
                output += ' ';
            } else if (char === '>') {
                if (mode === 'TAG' || mode === 'CLOSING_TAG') {
                    indent += mode === 'TAG' ? +1 : -1;

                    shouldBreakAfter = breakAfter.indexOf(tag) >= 0;
                    inTag = false;
                    tag = '';
                }
                output += '>';
                output += shouldBreakAfter ? br(indent) : '';
            } else {
                output += char;

                if (inTag) {
                    tag += char;
                }
            }

            return output;
        }, '');
}
```

**sass:**

```
export const prettifyScss = (scss) => {
    let indent = 0,
        closeBefore = 0;

    return scss
        .split('')
        .reduce((output, char) => {

            closeBefore++;

            if (char === '{') {
                indent++;
                output += '{' + br(indent);
            } else if (char === '}') {
                indent--;
                output += br(indent) + '}' + (closeBefore > 3 ? '\n' : '') + _tabs(indent);
                closeBefore = 0;
            } else if (char === '.') {
                output += br(indent) + '.';
            } else if (char === ';') {
                output += ';' + br(indent);
            } else {
                output += char;
            }

            return output;
        }, '');
}
```

**helper methods:**

```
const _tabs = (number) => {
    let output = '';

    for (let cnt = 0; cnt < number; cnt++) {
        output += '\t';
    }

    return output;
}

const br = (indent) => {
    return '\n' + _tabs(indent);
}

export const whichTag = (html, index) => {
    let inTag = true,
        tag = '';

    const arr = html.split('');

    for (let i = index + 1; i < index + 10; i++) {
        const char = arr[i];

        if (char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' && inTag) {
            tag += char;
        } else if (char !== '/') {
            inTag = false;
        }
    }

    return tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In beautify file just point beautify to windows(global object) after that you can call beautify from the global object.
ext-beautify.js on row 330 add

```js
window.beautify = exports;
```

Then you can use it.

```js
vm.session = vm.editor.getSession();
beautify.beautify(vm.session);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ace editor use beautify only for `php`, - it is written in ace docs.

For me, the best solution was `https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify`

There are a lot of settings, `Js/CSS/HTML` beautifying, work with `npm`, with `python`, by `import`, by `required` etc.

```js
import beautify from 'js-beautify';

// your code

beautifyHTML() {
    this.html = beautify.html(this.html, {
      indent_size: '2',
      indent_char: ' ',
      max_preserve_newlines: '5',
      preserve_newlines: true,
      keep_array_indentation: false,
      break_chained_methods: false,
      indent_scripts: 'normal',
      brace_style: 'expand',
      space_before_conditional: true,
      unescape_strings: false,
      jslint_happy: false,
      end_with_newline: false,
      wrap_line_length: '80',
      indent_inner_html: true,
      comma_first: false,
      e4x: false
    });
  }
```

see more docs and settings [here](https://beautifier.io/)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to execute the `beautify.beautify` after window is loaded when open the page so that `editor.session` is initialized.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  beautify.beautify(editor.session)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue but fixed it by adding two script files.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/ext-beautify.js"></script>
```