# Is there any way to set options in beautify extension for Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I've found the beautify extension in Ace editor but I don't see any examples of how to use it. Is there a way to set any options?

Example what I have so far:

```
var beautiful = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify"); // get extension
var editor = ace.edit("editor"); // reference to our editor
editor.setValue(someCode); // add some code to the editor
beautiful.beautify(editor.session); // beautify the code
```

When I call this method the code is formatted but it is all unindented / outdented all the way to the left and some spaces are removed. It doesn't look quite right. So I want to know if there are any options. I looked at the code but it is minified. Which is why I'm asking this question here.

Before call:
[image]

After call:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I found an unminifed copy of the extension. It looks like there are no options and it looks like it only works for PHP:

```
exports.beautify = function(session) {
    var iterator = new TokenIterator(session, 0, 0);
    var token = iterator.getCurrentToken();

    var context = session.$modeId.split("/").pop();

    var code = phpTransform(iterator, context);
    session.doc.setValue(code);
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use beautify in Ace Editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767051/how-do-i-use-beautify-in-ace-editor)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - great username. I started looking for feedback button to report Stack Exchange site bug. I know how to call the beautify method but I don't know how to set any options on it or even if options are available. I'll update the question.

Comment: I've updated the question. It looks like it only works for PHP and there are no options on the beautify() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any options in the beautify.js code for the beautify() method. I found a comment saying that it is not being worked on or supported any more. I do not have the source but it said it was not working and was then abandoned.

It might work alright for JavaScript but is not working well for ActionScript.