# Ace Editor's beautify extention not formatting HTML onto new lines as expected

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to use Ace editor with the beautify extension.

If I try to beautify the content :

```
<div><ul><li>aaaaa</li></ul></div>
```

I would expect to get :

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li>aaaaa</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

No such change happens though and it stays as one long line of code.

Need to get it so it works as expected.

JS Fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/treefishuk/t03sh2fc/

Comment: There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54916594/9026103) with beautify js lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also tried beautify extension of ace editor and it was not working for me as well, output was in single line only. I have gone through [JS Beautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) and it works perfectly fine. It has options to beautify JS, HTML and CSS. You can use HTML module to beautify your code in Ace Editor. I have attached the sample code below for same:

HTML:

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

JS:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var val = "<div><ul><li>aaaaa</li></ul></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>";
val = html_beautify(val);
editor.setValue(val, 1);
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
```

Running [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urq27dku/5/) link.

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you @ali