# prettifying innerHTML from Contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, contenteditable

I am trying to make an editor using contenteditible `div`(this `div` will show the rendered content but will also allow user to make changes by typing and other toolbar tools like bold, italic and so on), lets call this editor *renditor*, I also want to show the innerHTML of contenteditible `div` in another div for which I am using ace-editor for angular(https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor) with mode html(lets call it *coditor*) but the problem I am facing is when I toggle from renditor to coditor(I take innerHTML of *renditor* `div` and plug it into *coditor* `div`) the *renditor* changes the look of `innerHTML` in its own mysterious way which results in overflows in *coditor*.

I have tried to use a pipe in angular with code provided from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794051/4961540) but that even worsen the issue by breaking the html. I also feel *renditor* `div` is responsible for this because in past I didn't used separate `div` like *coditor* to show the code rather I just toggled in the same `div` using tags like `pre` and some other helper functions even then the html looked like it is looking now in *coditor*. Also it feels like *renditor* is responsible for it because I have observed when I set `innerHTML` of *renditor* to full html page source, it strips out `html` tags and some other tags so it is indeed making some changes to `innerHTML` and also how it looks.

```
 <div class="mat-typography textBox editable" style="margin: 16px;" 
  [hidden]="isSourceVisible" 
  (input)="mSimpleTask.html=$event.target.innerHTML"contenteditable="true">
  </div>

    <div class="ace_tooltip" [hidden]="!isSourceVisible" ace-editor 
    [(text)]="mSimpleTask.html" 
    [mode]="'html'"
    class="textBox ace-editor" 
    [theme]="'eclipse'"
    [readOnly]="false"
    [autoUpdateContent]="true"
    [durationBeforeCallback]="1000"
    (textChanged)="this.mSimpleTask.html=$event;"
    style="overflow-wrap: break-word;margin: 16px">

  </div>
```

I am looking to convert/extract `innerHTML` from *renditor* in such a way that html looks neat with proper line breaks and no overflows in *coditor*. Can you throw some light on how I can achieve that or even better if you can provide code with your implementation in the past ?